# MySQL storing list of values

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have 300,000 rows in my db and I am doing a full text search like this:

```
select * from CT
where match (`Abstract`)
against ('tissue engineering' in natural language mode);
```

Right now it is checking to see if the word "tissue engineering" is found in the abstract, however, I have a list of around 50 terms I need to check for. My first response is to create a list of all the values and check it against the list. Is this possible with MySQL?

```
#How to write this in MySQL?
terms = ['abdomen', 'abdominal', 'acl'...'vertebral', 'waist', 'wrist']
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in natural language mode? Have you tried WHERE ABSTRACT REGEXP 'abdomen|abdominal|waist|wrist'?

Comment: What is REGEXP? I'm pretty new to MySQL. I come from a python background 

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html